# Are questions about [labview] still on topic?

Tags: discussion

As shown in the electronics.SE [FAQ](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq)

> and it is not about …
>
> - a shopping or buying recommendation
> - consumer electronics such as media
>     players, cell phones or smart phones,
>     except when designing these products
>     or hacking their electronics for other
>     uses
> - **Programming software for a PC**

So should I post labview questions here or there?
There are only [87](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/labview) questions tagged as labview on StackOverflow so maybe it will do better at electronics.

Labview is a {visual} programming language but most if not all the times ... there is some sort of DAQ component (electronics ?) as well.
So where should it go ?

Comment: LabVIEW is most useful in Code-Golf questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169051/code-golf-word-frequency-chart/3173781#3173781

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is about the DAQ hardware I'd ask it on Electronics SE.  Since the software you write in LabVIEW runs on a PC and only communicates with the DAQ, I'd keep asking LabVIEW programming questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: What about VHDL? Is that a programming language that belongs on SO, or a hardware schematic that belongs on E.SE?

Comment: @Gabe: Good question.  I've never worked in VHDL before, so I don't know the answer (although I'm leaning towards E.SE since it's about hardware design).  The tag already exists on both sites, so I'd ask it as a separate question.  I think it's going to come down to which site attracts more VHDL experts.

Answer (score 3):

Clearly not e.se.  Niche software development tools don't do well at SO.  You can try your luck but you'd have to be patient, the two top rated answerers only seem to visit once a month or so.

There's no substitute for a vendor supported forum.  [National Instrument's](http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/bd-p/170) is quite active.  If you're unhappy with it then consider starting your own SE site, click the area 51 link at the bottom of the page.

Comment: +1 for the NI site/forums.  There have always been a lot of good articles posted there, and a lot of helpful users when I worked with the language.  There was already a [LabVIEW proposal on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28390/ni-labview), but I suggested it be closed as redundant a while ago.